# How to use 'both due to' in a sentence?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

I'm a non-native speaker and I'm having trouble using ***both due to*** in a sentence.

I want to describe a certain thing, let's say 'A', is a result of two processes, 'B' and 'C'.

I remembered a friend of mine who is a native English speaker advising me to use 'both due to', but I can't remember exactly how.

Comment: "'A', is a result of two processes, 'B' and 'C'." is **not** a suitable example case for the use of *both due to*. This question might be GR, but considering your earnest, I'm posting a short answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I am afraid this question may be considered too open-ended and/or too basic for this site. You might be interested in our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Comment: @RegDwighт An open-ended question is one that has more than one possible definite answer. One that is too basic would be with a clear and definite answer, not open to debate. At least I thought so. :)

Answer (score 3):

The given sentence is not a suitable example. Instead, consider:

```
A is a result of X    } 
and                   } -> A and B are both due to X  
B is a result of X    }
```

We notice that A and B are both caused by X. Therefore, they are ***both due to*** X.

An alternate situation is where

```
A is a result of X    } 
and                   } -> A is both due to X as well as Y
A is a result of Y    }
```

*His failure is both due to his lack of preparation as well his poor health.*
However, this is a less preferred construction and may be considered awkward.

Comment: I'd probably rephrase the second one as "A is due to X, and A is due to Y as well." (Your sentence is not wrong per se, but I thought the first one reads much more naturally.)

Comment: Surely your second example is a perfect demonstration of where *due both to* should be used rather than *both due to*.

Comment: @J.R. Yes. It was so structured as to merely illustrate the (possible) use of the phrase '*both due to*' -- a hypothetical case, if you will.

Comment: @TimLymington Agreed. Please see my comment above. However, I did add the alert: "a less preferred construction and may be considered awkward."

Comment: It's not "awkward": it's merely syntactically and semantically wrong, an example of how native speakers will say anything regardless of whether it says what they mean or means what they want to say & then claim that it's correct because they're native speakers & understand what it means & expect everyone else to read their mind.

Comment: The second case could be rephrased as *due both to X and to Y*.

Comment: @PeterShor I already answered that saying the purpose was to illustrate  the phrase *both due to* -- not necessarily to be pedantic -- and therefore included the clarification. Up voters to your comment seem to have exercised no circumspection whatsoever. That happens naturally with the higher profiles, who need to be circumspect themselves first. One may have to ascribe the down vote to this answer indirectly to the misconstrued comments?

Comment: @Kris: I think you're being a little overly literal here. If somebody asked how to use the phrase "let the dogs lose", would you use that phrase in your answer, or would you give an answer using: "let the dogs loose"? My guess is that the friend of the OP meant "due both to", whether or not that is was they said.

Comment: @PeterShor Possible. However, one is *expected* to be literal, not include one's own conjectures, interpretations, extrapolations or what-could-have-been's here, right? The title is unambiguous, as is the first sentence, with no scope for speculation.

Answer (score 1):

"X is due to Y" means that Y caused X. You've got it the wrong way round.
You could say "A is due to both B and C", but then that could be interpreted as either B or C on its own could result in A.
So you may be best to say something like, "A is due to a combination of B and C", to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: *Due to a combination of B and C* is fine, as is *due to both B and C*, though with a slightly different meaning. But *due to a combination of both B and C* is pleonastic at best, and misleading at worst.

Comment: See my comment at OP.

Comment: @TimLymington: Good point. I've edited out the "both". I didn't see that "combination of both" could be taken to mean some hybrid process of B and C. In that light I'm still not happy with my choice of the word "combination".

Answer (score -1):

*Due to* is understood as *caused by*.

Back in the dark ages of the 1960s we were taught to distinguish between *necessary* and *sufficient* causes.

If **B** and **C** are each, independently, *sufficient* causes of **A**, this may be expressed most succinctly by

> **A** may be due to either **B** or **C**.

The *may be* is not strictly necessary; but it is to my mind preferable to *is* in order to avoid misunderstanding.

If **B** and **C** are both *necessary* causes of **A** but neither is a *sufficient* cause in the absence of the other, the use with *both* is accurate but, again, may be misunderstood; it should be qualified with an additional phrase (here bracketed—another phrase may suit the particular context better):

> **A** is due to both **B** and **C** [operating together].

It gets more complicated if a third cause, necessary or sufficient, is involved.